# Is it possible to make gedmo-root field to be foreign key?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, tree

I use next libraries:

```
"gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "2.3.*",
"stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "1.1.*"
```

Is it possible to make gedmo-root field to be a foreign key like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SP\EventBundle\Entity\Event")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="event_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 * @Gedmo\TreeRoot
 */
private $event;
```

Do i need another field for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do it. You need addition column for `@Gedmo\TreeRoot`.

For more details look at `lib/Gedmo/Tree/Mapping/Driver/Annotation.php`:

```
if ($this->reader->getPropertyAnnotation($property, self::ROOT)) {
    $field = $property->getName();
    if (!$meta->hasField($field)) {
        throw new InvalidMappingException("Unable to find 'root' - [{$field}] as mapped property in entity - {$meta->name}");
    }

    if (!$validator->isValidFieldForRoot($meta, $field)) {
        throw new InvalidMappingException("Tree root field - [{$field}] type is not valid and must be any of the 'integer' types or 'string' in class - {$meta->name}");
    }
    $config['root'] = $field;
}
```

$meta contains only common field of entity, not FK!